# Why does my application not register with Eureka server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple spring boot application that should register with Eureka.  I used the new annotation @EnableDiscoveryClient but still no action at startup.  The class is declared as follows, and has a single request mapping.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class SpringBootEchoApplication {
```

I see no error messages or anything a startup, I just don't get any discovery client logging like I do in my other app which uses the annotation to enable zuul.

Answer (score 2):

After checking the dependencies in the two projects, the one in which I was not getting eureka registration did not include the eureka-client dependency.

I guess this is a drawback to the @Conditional configuration way of doing things in boot.  Even though I have the appropriate Enable annotation specified, because I have no DiscoveryClient implementation (like Eureka) I get no registration... but also no error messages.